# External commands sent to Python Interactive Console?

Tags: python, game-engine, command-line, external-applications

Comrades, I figured out how to open a .blend file using an separate/external Python script, I would now like to know how to send instructions to the Python Interactive Console? The code below is run from a simple Idle Python3.3 module. The commented line does not work - any suggestions on how to fix this? I want to call the Embedded Player to run automatically from another script.

```
import os

def openFile():
    try:
        os.startfile('bob2.blend')
        os.system('Python:bpy.ops.view3d.game_start()')#start embedded player??
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

I am aware that making the .blend file a .exe will solve this problem but the will make development very slow as I will have to compile the BGE every time I change code...
Thanks guys!

Comment: Why don't you run the game engine in Blender by hitting *P* during the development? It has a decent text editor with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to implement a program that makes use of semaphores (running two program simultaneously), so I need the .blend file to run the embedded player intimidatingly. If you know how to send the command that is executed when 'P' is pressed then I can send that through the Python IDLE master script to the BGE's Embedded Player. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: See related question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41533

Answer (score 2):

If running the exe works, you could also open the blend *with* blenderplayer and not worry about exporting.

```
os.system('/path/to/blenderplayer.exe bob2.blend')
```