# Run Python code from external process

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way for an external process (e.g. shell command) to cause Blender to execute a fragment of Python code (on Linux)?

Essentially I would like to make my own version of the "Python Console" that runs separately and sends commands to Blender (which is already running and continues to run as normal with commands being received in the background.)

Answer (score 3):

I see two approaches to this.

1. You can compile entire blender as python module (completely without user interface) and use it inside an external python script.

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule

2. A custom solution. as described here.

[How to remotely run a Python script in an existing Blender instance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41533/how-to-remotely-run-a-python-script-in-an-existing-blender-instance)

Comment: Thank you! I think the second link would make a good basis for what I want.

Comment: Great link, thank you also!